# stringstream and for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, stringstream

I'm using a stringstream to generate "dynamically", the name of the files I need to open and this is my  code:

```
for (int img=0; img<5; img++)
{
stringstream stream;
string *s=new string("myfile");
stream << img << ".png"
s->append(stream.str());

.. other code
```

the problem is than the first time the program flows into the loop it works fine, the second time stream does not has the value "1.png", but has value null... so when I try to open the file I get a null pointer.

ho do I fix this?

Comment: your allocating s in the loop, could you post the rest of the code?

Comment: Why use a `stringstream` and not just append `img` and ".png" just as you do the streams string!?

Comment: Is there a reason you use a `string` pointer? You do remember to `delete` it?

Comment: the next instruction is
fore=cvLoadImage(s->c_str());
double mean=cvAvg(fore, maskbg).val[0];

as I said it works in the first time, but I get null pointer the second time.. and the null pointer is fore.

Comment: @andrea:  why are you doing `new string` in the first place?  You should probably just do: `string s = "myfile";`

Comment: hmm, sorry I was little too quick with answering this. Please do post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try allocating your string before your loop.

`string *s = new string("myfile");`

`for(;;;){} //forloop` 
// use s here.

`delete s;`  // always delete dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: or just don't allocate on the heap if there is no need to pass around a mutable string.

Comment: Yes, no reason to dynamically allocate memory here. Your solution will leak memory if an exception is thrown inside the `for` loop. The "always delete dynamically allocate memory" should be "if you use dynamically allocated memory, and consider if you **really** want to do that, then use an RAII object (i.e. smart pointer) to manage deletion for you"

Comment: @TamásSzelei or use smart pointer such as shared_ptr, or unique_ptr. I dont question andrea's motives, though i do whole heatedly agree with you.

Comment: the point is not on s, but on stream. when I append the stream to s it does not append anything in the second loop

Comment: @andrea your appending to a new string on every iteration. .. and the old string is memory leaked if its not deleted. move the allocation of your string outside of your loop. And be sure you place the deletion of the string after your done using it.

Comment: @andrea , also, seriously consider using std::shared_ptr, or std::unique_ptr for your dynamically allocated objects, that way you wont have to worry about delete.

Comment: it almost works now, just a last question. now I append to a string that is not cleanes. so my string is like mystring0.pnh, mystring0.png1.png how I restore the string to the original value "mystring2 without allocating it again?

Comment: @andrea you can use the substr() function , along with operator = , such as (*s) = s->substr(0,iLen); where iLen is the length of the string you want to return from substr, and 0 is the position in the string you want to start from. So (*s) = s->substr(0,9); should give you "mystring2" back into s.

Comment: @andrea thats just 1 way, there are several ways depending on what you need to accomplish with the code as a whole. Give that a try though.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution:

```
for (int img = 0; img < 5; ++img)
{
    std::string s = "myfile" + ('0' + img) + ".png";

    // do something useful with s
}
```

If numbers are bigger than 9, you can use `std::to_string(img)` instead.

Comment: std::to_string does not exists

Comment: @andrea: You may have an old compiler. In GCC or Clang, include `<string>` and compile with `-std=c++0x`; MSVC10 should already support this.

Comment: I'm using VS2008. and I have to use it.

Comment: @andrea: In that case, use `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(img)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB in vs 08 to_string resides in the tr1 namespace